# Why is my Syno NAS creating a snapshot each hour instead of one per day?

Tags: replication, snapshot, synology

**[Background information]**

I am running a Synology DS916+ consisting of 4 disks forming 2 storage pools. Storage pool 1 is made up of 3 disks holding all my data on a SHR (Syno Hybrid RAID). Storage pool 2 is only made up of disk 4 which is holding my backup.

To backup my data I am using the `Snapshot Replication` utility provided by DSM. This is what the configuration looks like on one of my shares. I have made snapshots visible on `pictures` but not on `pictures-1`

[image: https://i.imgur.com/UH4o0bD.png]

**[Question]**

Why is my NAS creating a snapshot each hour on the share `\\nas\pictures` as opposed to one per day?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You replication is based on snapshots and your replication frequency is set to *Every 1 hours*. This will make a snapshot of *pictures* every hour and replicate that snapshot to *pictures-1*.

I am not familiar with the Synology stuff, but it seems that the snapshots are not cleaned up. There is a *Retentionn Policy* that can be set to control the amount of snapshots kept. But you will have to keep at least the latest snapshot used by replication.

More info on that can be [found here](https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/SnapshotReplication/data_protection_mgr).